# How to check if a process with a pid X is a zombie?

Tags: c, process, posix

I got the PID of a process and I need to check if it is a zombie using POSIX system calls in C. How should I do that?

The problem I'm having is that I have a process and it forks into many children, the children all do execs and sometimes I want to do the exec in background so I can't really wait() the children that go in background. I could wait() periodically (once in my main loop) but I need to know which processes are zombie so my father process doesn't hang while waiting for children that are not going to end soon.

If you are curious, I'm building a unix shell and it is in the shell nature to have the children processes behaving asynchronously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't check whether a process is a zombie with pure POSIX calls - except where you're the parent process, and reaping it with a [`wait` family](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/wait.html) call. So you'll have to find a good place to wait for the child.

One option is to set a `SIGCHLD` handler and do a `waitpid(0, &status, WNOHANG)` there. Be sure to loop until it no longer finds any processes - if two children die within a short interval, you may only get one `SIGCHLD`.

Another option is to double fork - that is, `fork()`, have the child (call it child A) fork again, have the second child (child B) exec. Then child A immediately exits. Meanwhile the parent is `wait()`ing for child A. Once child A is gone, the system's init process will take care of reaping child B when it eventually dies. This method is simpler, but your shell will have no way of knowing when child B dies, so if you need that information, use the former method.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using your first suggestion. Your second suggestion is also interesting but it would be too much a hassle to implement and probably have performance hit due to double forking.

Comment: Forking is very fast on many (most?) modern Unix-like systems and many tricks are employed (this is bread and butter for a kernel). Please don't judge it as "being slow" without a performance analysis.

Answer (score 3):

But .. but .. the zombie is a child (at some level) and the process that's checking is a parent, right? So if you are concerned that a specific pid is a zombie why not just do a `waitpid(2)` with `WNOHANG` and get rid of it? Now, this will consume the exit status, so it may be a bad idea if some other process might want to really `wait` in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that wait could return immediately with that option (btw, it's WNOHANG).

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you are building a Unix shell; you should read this: [Proper handling of SIGINT/SIGQUIT](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html)

Comment: Interesting paper.  I question whether emacs runs in the half-cooked mode where key strokes still generate signals; most curses-based programs run with raw-mode terminal settings, in which case the terminal driver generates no signals to the program for SIGINT or SIGQUIT; the program just gets the keystrokes like any other control character.

Comment: Emacs does indeed get signals from keystrokes. It also reassigns C-g (^G) as the key for SIGINT, and last I checked it does some really nasty non-portable longjumping-out-of-signal-handlers stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the shell checks for defunct children shortly before printing its prompt - using the `waitpid(2)` system call and the `WNOHANG` option as already discussed.  You might also want a SIGCHLD handler - but you'd have to decide what you're going to do with the information if you're busy waiting for some foreground process to terminate and it is actually a background process that terminates.

This is only a minor variation on the currently selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

And what about the shell command 'ps' which shows you the table of active processes where you can find that an process is 'defunct'? I suppose there must be a way to get that information from c code.

Comment: I suppose you could use the system() call and parse the result, but that would be platform dependent (and also dependent on the system having the ps command installed, which is not guaranteed). The ps program is not a part of the POSIX spec. Also calling an external program would involve string parsing and forking another process which would be very slow and very ugly.