# Zombie process - Finding it

Tags: c, ubuntu

I used inotify() function in my program to monitor /proc directory. Now my job is to find when a process become zombie. Then i need output a warning that zombie process was found. At the moment program is recording some of the changes but i don't know how to find zombie process..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int inotify_fd, wd;
    int num;

    char buffer[sizeof(struct inotify_event)+NAME_MAX+1];  
    struct inotify_event *dogodek;

    inotify_fd = inotify_init();  
    if (inotify_fd==-1) {
        perror("inotify_init");
        return 1;
    }


    wd = inotify_add_watch(inotify_fd, "/proc/",IN_ALL_EVENTS);  
    if (wd==-1) {                                                     
        perror("inotify_add_watch");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Map gots descriptor %d\n",wd);

    int f;
    for (f=0; f<20; f++) {  
        num=read(inotify_fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (num>0) {
            dogodek=(struct inotify_event*)buffer; 

            printf("Access to map with descriptor %d\n", dogodek->wd);
            if (dogodek->len>0)  
                printf("\tevent found: %s\n", dogodek->name);
            else
                printf("\tevent found in directory!\n");


            printf("\tMask of the event %x\n", dogodek->mask);
            if (dogodek->mask & IN_ACCESS)
                printf("\t\tReading file!\n");

            if (dogodek->mask & IN_CREATE) 
                printf("\t\tCreating file!\n");

            if (dogodek->mask & IN_DELETE) 
                printf("\t\tDeleting file!\n");

            if (dogodek->mask & IN_OPEN) 
                printf("\t\tOpening file!\n");




        }
    }
    inotify_rm_watch(inotify_fd, wd); 
    return 0;
}
```

I need example in code not just explation if there is a possibility.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a process with a pid X is a zombie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619020/how-to-check-if-a-process-with-a-pid-x-is-a-zombie)

Comment: maybe there is some of the similarities but i wroted a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following applies to Linux (at least):

- The status of a process can be found in `/proc/[pid]/status`.
- For a zombie the file `/proc/[pid]/cmdline` is empty, that is reading from it returns `0` bytes.

For details please see here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html